# Как запретить доступ к папкам чужих сайтов на хостинге в режиме apache + FastCGI? Аналог open_basedir

Tags: php, apache, centos, fastcgi

Есть свой хостинг. Установлен CentOS, apache и FastCGI. Если сайт выводить в режиме "PHP как модуль Apache" с включенной опцией open_basedir, то скриптам система не дает лазить за пределами своей домашней директории (знаю, что есть обходные пути, но сейчас не про это). Если этот же сайт перевести в режим "PHP в режиме FastCGI", то я могу лазить скриптами вплоть до корня сервера.
В vhost указана директива "SuexecUserGroup myuser myuser".
Как сделать так, чтобы в режиме FastCGI запретить скриптам лазить за пределы своей домашней папки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методом проб и ошибок нашел, что если в php.ini указать параметр open_basedir = /var/www/ и перезагрузить апач, то за пределы /var/www/ скрипт уже не может вылезти. Т.е. параметр php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www:.", указанный в vhost.conf, влияет на работу сайта в режиме "модуля Apache", а параметр open_basedir, указанный в php.ini влияет на работу сайта в режиме FastCGI. Блин, бился около недели...